# Is it possible to make full-colour Holography using three lasers and three separate holograms?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, waves, fourier-transform, hologram

Holograms need **monochromatic** coherent light sources like lasers so that the reference light can interfere with the light scattered by the object. Illuminating the holograms, the stored interference patterns, with the same reference laser reconstructs the 3D holographic virtual images but with same **monochromatic light.**

I was wondering if it is possible to use three different holograms (each one displaced by the same amount as the thickness on one plate) to capture the same scene with red, blue and green light, one at a time, and then stick all three holograms together to get a full-color RGB hologram that can work in **normal white light conditions**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "normal white light conditions".  Certainly three holograms made as you describe can display a full color (that is, RGB) image.  But it is necessary to use a white light source that is effectively spatially coherent to get a sharp reconstruction: a tensor light or a clear incandescent bulb works well.  A diffuse source like fluorescent bulbs produces a blurry reconstruction.